# Looking to setup SSO in JBoss EAP 7 using kerberos on windows server

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, jboss7.x, kerberos, windows-authentication

I'm new to JBoss and have been assigned a task to implement SSO (JBoss EAP 7) on Windows Server using Kerberos.

Tried google but resulted in confusion.

Could you please share few detailed steps to achieve the task.

Answer (score 1):

The JBoss documentation contains instructions for configuring Kerberos:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/how_to_set_up_sso_with_kerberos/